# Unit Testing With Pyserial-Asyncio

Tags: python, unit-testing, asynchronous, pyserial, python-asyncio

I have a [github issue](https://github.com/FaradayRF/faradayio/issues/3#issuecomment-350653922) I am trying to figure out. Basically, I am attempting to use [pyserial-asyncio](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial-asyncio/) to connect to a serial port asynchronously. However, I would like to unit test it and am learning this all at the same time. What's throwing me for a loop (pun intended) is that When I [use the pyserial-asyncio unit test](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial-asyncio/blob/master/test/test_asyncio.py) I can get it to work. This does seem to create a very specialized test which doesn't bode well with integrating the asynchronous functions into a module. **Mainly, I can't seem to understand how I would implement this in a module and then check the values in each function.**

**Output Class (Asyncio.Protocol)**
Below I've implemented an asyncio.Protocol similar to that needed for unit testing pyserial-asyncio. This is implemented in the test as an imported object "faradayOut = faraday.Output"

```
class Output(asyncio.Protocol):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self._transport = None
    self.received = []
    self.actions = []
    self.TEXT = b'Hello, World!\n'

def connection_made(self, transport):
    self._transport = transport
    self.actions.append('open')
    transport.write(self.TEXT)

def data_received(self, data):
    self.received.append(data)
    if b'\n' in data:
        self._transport.close()
    return data

def connection_lost(self, exc):
    self.actions.append('close')
    self._transport.loop.stop()

def pause_writing(self):
    self.actions.append('pause')
    print(self._transport.get_write_buffer_size())

def resume_writing(self):
    self.actions.append('resume')
    print(self._transport.get_write_buffer_size())
```

This is used in the test below:

```
import os
import unittest
import asyncio

import serial_asyncio

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
_PORT = 8888
```

on which port should the tests be performed:

```
PORT = 'socket://%s:%s' % (HOST, _PORT)

@unittest.skipIf(os.name != 'posix', "asyncio not supported on platform")
class Test_asyncio(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test asyncio related functionality"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        # create a closed serial port

    def tearDown(self):
        self.loop.close()

    def test_asyncio(self):
        faradayIn = faraday.Input
        faradayOut = faraday.Output
        if PORT.startswith('socket://'):
            coro = self.loop.create_server(faradayIn, HOST, _PORT)
            self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)

        client = serial_asyncio.create_serial_connection(self.loop, faradayOut, PORT)
        self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(client))
        # print("TEST = {0}".format(test))
        self.loop.run_forever()
        # self.assertEqual(b''.join(client.received), faraday.Output.TEXT)
        # self.assertEqual(actions, ['open', 'close'])
```

This works. The problem is that I cannot check the client.received text against faraday.Output.TEXT. This is because once the aysncio loop completes the coroutine seems to be destroyed and with it that instances self.received list.

How can I unit test this with the intended implementation?